# Why does this C++ program return different results between Code::Blocks and an online IDE?

Tags: c++

While asking for help on a [C++ program to convert binary numbers to integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917003/converting-binary-to-integer-in-c-returns-weird-results), @dasblinkenlight wrote the following program. Using the Ideone IDE and also Repl.it, I noticed that it returns the expected value `482`. However, using a local IDE (`Code::Blocks` tested in 2 computers), this same program returns the value `506`. Why does this happen?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int int_length(int bit_number);
int bin_to_int(int bit_number);

int main()
{
    cout << bin_to_int(111100010) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int int_length(int bit_number){
    bool found = false;
    int digit_count = 0;

    while(!found){
        int division = bit_number / pow(10, digit_count);
        if(division < 1){
            found = true;
        }
        else{
            digit_count++;
        }
    }
    return digit_count;
}

int bin_to_int(int bit_number){
    int number_length = int_length(bit_number);

    int number = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < number_length; i++){
        int e = pow(10, i);
        int digit = (bit_number / e) % 10;
        digit = digit * pow(2, i);
        number = number + digit;
    }

    return number;

}
```

Comment: This seems like the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: g++ -o mycode mycode.cpp && mycode   ... I am seeing 482 ... what does this say on your machine just using a terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pow` is a floating point function and so there is the possibility of rounding errors. For an overview see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

In particular the line:

```
int e = pow(10, i);
```

may cause a problem. The calcluation might work out to , say `9999.999999983732`  and then when you truncate this to integer you get `9999` rather than `10000`, leading to a wrong result.

You could verify this hypothesis by inspecting the value of `e` for each loop iteration (either with a debugger, or an output statement).  There could be a similar problem for the other use of `pow(10, digit_count)`.

One way to fix it is to use a rounding function, although IMO a better solution is to not use `pow` at all. Instead write a function with a loop for doing integer exponentiation (there is no standard function for that purpose).

IMO the advice you linked to use `pow(2, i)` is poor. Although powers of 2 will work out exactly on common systems, the reader might not realize that using `pow` with integers other than a power of 2 has problems. (And C++ does actually have syntax for integer exponentiation of `2`, namely `1 << i`).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @M.M, writting a custom power function makes the compiler return the expected value. @Some programmer dude, while debugging I noticed the precision error while calculating the power of the numbers.

This is the fully working code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int int_length(int bit_number);
int bin_to_int(int bit_number);

int main()
{
    cout << bin_to_int(111100010) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int power(int number, int p){

    if(p < 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(p == 1){
        return number;
    }
    else if(p > 1){
        int result = number;
        for(int i = 1; i < p; i++){
            result = result * number;
        }
        return result;
    }

}

int int_length(int bit_number){
    bool found = false;
    int digit_count = 0;

    while(!found){
        int division = bit_number / power(10, digit_count);
        if(division < 1){
            found = true;
        }
        else{
            digit_count++;
        }
    }
    return digit_count;
}

int bin_to_int(int bit_number){
    int number_length = int_length(bit_number);

    int number = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < number_length; i++){
        int e = power(10, i);
        int digit = (bit_number / e) % 10;
        digit = digit * power(2, i);
        number = number + digit;
    }

    return number;

}
```